# I am getting an "Undefined variable" error in CodeIgniter when fetching from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting error in codeigniter while fetching from the database.

Here is my error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Message: Undefined variable: results
>
> Line Number: 122

Here is my code:

```
  <?php $via = $this->session->userdata('firm_name');
if(!isset($firm_name)){ redirect ('Welcome');}
?>      
<link href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/radiostyle.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
              .page-heading {
            border-top: 0;
            padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
        }
        input, button, select, textarea{
          margin: 10px;
        }
              .ibox-content {
          background-color: #ffffff;
          color: inherit;
          padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;
          border-color: #e7eaec;
          border-image: none;
          border-style: none; 
          border-width: 1px 0px;
      }
      </style>
      
            <div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
                <div style="float: left;" class="col-lg-4">
                    <img style="    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;     padding-top: 5px;" src="http://www.miisky.com/ci/GST.png" alt="GST Logo">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
                    <h1 style="    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-right: 20%;">Know Your Customers</h1>
                    
                </div>
                <div style="float: right;" class="col-lg-4">
                    <h1 style="padding-top:9px"><?php echo "Date: ". date("d/m/Y");?></h1>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><div style="text-align: center;"> 
            <label class="control control--radio">Manufacture
      <input type="radio" onclick="document.location='#';" name="radio" checked="checked"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
    <label class="control control--radio">Service
      <input type="radio" onclick="document.location='#';" name="radio" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
     <label class="control control--radio">Trading
      <input type="radio" onclick="document.location='#';" name="radio" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
    <label class="control control--radio">Others
      <input type="radio" onclick="document.location='#';" name="radio" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
   
    
  
    </div>
            <div class="fh-breadcrumb">

                <div class="full-height">
                    <div class="full-height-scroll white-bg border-left">
                      <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
                        <div class="element-detail-box">

                            <div class="tab-content">
                               <div class="ibox-content">
            
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    
                                    <?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>
                                    <?php $attributes = array("name" => "Categoryform","autocomplete"=>"off");
                                    echo form_open("Gst_customer/customersearch/", $attributes);?>
                                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                        <input name="CustomerName" type="text" placeholder="CustomerName" value="<?php echo set_value('CustomerName'); ?>" class="form-control" required>
                                                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('CustomerName'); ?></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                       <?php echo form_submit('Search', 'Search','class="btn btn-info"'); ?>
                                                    </div> 
                                                    
                                      <?php echo form_close(); ?>

                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                     
            </div>

                               

                                
                                
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
<div class="full-height">
                      <div class="full-height-scroll white-bg border-left">
                         <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>
                          <div class="element-detail-box">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
              <?php if(isset($results)){ ?>
<table class='table table-bordered'>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                      <th> Customer Name </th>
                      <th> Customer Id</th>
                      <th> Customer Code</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          <?php foreach($results as $row){ ?>
                                    <tr>
                                         <td><?php echo $row->CustomerName;?></td>
                                         <td><?php echo $row->CustomerID;?></td>
                                         <td><?php echo $row->CustomerCode;?></td>
                                    </tr>

                          <?php } ?>


                      </tbody>
                  </table>
     <?php } ?>             

                  </tbody>
              </table>
          
                                      
                                 
                           
                       
           

                                 

                                  
                                  
                            
                          </div>
                          </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>


            </div>
```

This is my controller file:

```
<?php
class Gst_customer extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url','html'));
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        
    }   
    
    function index()
    {
        $details = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('id'));
                
        $data['firm_name'] = $details[0]->firm_name;
        $data['email'] = $details[0]->email;
        $data['vault_no'] = $details[0]->vault_no;
        $data['active'] = 'know_your_customer';
        $data['mobile'] = $details[0]->mobile;
        
        $this->load->view('view_header', $data);
        $this->load->view('view_menu', $data);
        $this->load->view('gst_customer_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('view_footer');
    }

     function customersearch()
    {
        $CustomerName    =   $this->input->post('CustomerName');
        $data['results']    =   $this->user_model->search($CustomerName);
        $results = $data['results'];
       $this->load->view('view_header', $data);
        $this->load->view('view_menu', $data);
        $this->load->view('gst_customer_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('view_footer');
    }

    function logout()
    {
    $user_data = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('id'));
        foreach ($user_data as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != 'session_id' && $key != 'ip_address' && $key != 'user_agent' && $key != 'last_activity') {
                $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
            }
        }
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    
    redirect('Welcome', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

This is my model:
**module.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class User_model extends CI_Model
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
            
        

function search($CustomerName,$CustomerID)
    {
        $this->db->like('CustomerName',$CustomerName);
        $this->db->like('CustomerID',$CustomerID);
        $query  =   $this->db->get('gst_customermaster');
        return $query->result();
    }
    
    }?>
```

Comment: What is name of view file? And in which action are you getting error?

Comment: view file name is gst_customer_view

Comment: may be you are getting this error in index action because in index() you are not passing results in view.

Comment: i need to fetch the data it is show like empty page...but error is cleared

Comment: Which data you want on index()?

Comment: customername,customerid,customercode i needed in index page

Comment: So you want all customers in index page?

Comment: yes i want all the data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all data in index. Try this:

**module.php**

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function search($CustomerName)
    {
        $this->db->like('CustomerName',$CustomerName);
        $query  =   $this->db->get('gst_customermaster');
        return $query->result();
    }

    function getAll()
    {            
        $query  =   $this->db->get('gst_customermaster');
        return $query->result();
    }

}?>`enter code here`
```

**controller file:**

```
 <?php
class Gst_customer extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url','html'));
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('user_model');

    }   

function index()
    {
        $details = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('id'));

        $data['firm_name'] = $details[0]->firm_name;
        $data['email'] = $details[0]->email;
        $data['vault_no'] = $details[0]->vault_no;
        $data['active'] = 'know_your_customer';
        $data['mobile'] = $details[0]->mobile;
        //$data['results']  =   $this->user_model->getAll();
        $data['results']  =   array();
        $this->load->view('view_header', $data);
        $this->load->view('view_menu', $data);
        $this->load->view('gst_customer_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('view_footer');
    }

     function customersearch()
    {
         $results = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('id'));
         $data['firm_name'] = $results[0]->firm_name;
           $id = $this->input->post('id');
       $data['results']=array();
        $CustomerName    =   $this->input->post('CustomerName');
       if(trim($CustomerName) != "")
       {
        $data['results']    =   $this->user_model->search($CustomerName);
       }
        $results = $data['results'];
       $this->load->view('view_header', $data);
        $this->load->view('view_menu', $data);
        $this->load->view('gst_customer_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('view_footer');
    }

    function logout()
    {
    $user_data = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('id'));
        foreach ($user_data as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != 'session_id' && $key != 'ip_address' && $key != 'user_agent' && $key != 'last_activity') {
                $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
            }
        }
    $this->session->sess_destroy();

    redirect('Welcome', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view.Show table if `$results` array is set.Because your are sending different data from different function to same view.

Like this..

```
<?php if(isset($results)){ ?>
<table class='table table-bordered'>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                      <th> Customer Name </th>
                      <th> Customer Id</th>
                      <th> Customer Code</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          <?php foreach($results as $row){ ?>
                                    <tr>
                                         <td><?php echo $row->CustomerName;?></td>
                                         <td><?php echo $row->CustomerID;?></td>
                                         <td><?php echo $row->CustomerCode;?></td>
                                    </tr>

                          <?php } ?>


                      </tbody>
                  </table>
     <?php } ?>
```

Comment: error is cleared...but not able to fetch the data...how to rectify that

Comment: you we see table data.only after executing customersearch function.

Comment: i have added model also...if any error is there pls tell me

Comment: CustomerName,CustomerID and CustomerCode are matching with database columns names or not?check

Comment: i am not able to fetch the data from database to display in view page it is coming like blank page...if any error is in model let me know

Comment: no any error in your model.also try         $this->load->database();
 in model.

Comment: i need to fetch the data from database to display in view page because i am able to do search part...